# Polymorphic serialization of collections with Custom Serializer in jackson

Tags: jackson, resteasy

How do i tell jackson to use a different serializer for each of the Generic collection type.
I have a CustomProductsSerializer and a CustomClientsSerializer

```
    public class ProductsListSerializer extends JsonSerializer<List<Products>>{

    // logic to insert __metadata , __count into json
    public void serialize(List<Products> value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) {
     .... .... .... 
     }
    // always returns ArrayList.class 
    public Class<List<Instrument>> handledType() {
    Class c = var.getClass();
    return c;
    }
    }


    public class CustomClientsSerializer extends JsonSerializer<List<Clients>>{

    // logic to insert __metadata , __count into json
    public void serialize(List<Clients> value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider){
     .... .... .... 
     }
     .... .... .... 
    // always returns ArrayList.class 
    public Class<List<Clients>> handledType() {
    Class c = var.getClass();
    return c;
    }
    }
```

I have registered both the serializers using SimpleModule. 
The problem is, since handledType in both cases returns ArrayList.class,  serialization of clients below fail with a class cast exception.

```
    List<Clients> clients;
    // code to get clients from database. 
    String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(clients);
```

Question is how to tell jackson about which serializer to use ?

I am using jackson as the json serializer with resteasy.

--Edit in response to @HiJon89
I have a business object which returns 'List' and another which returns List. The way I need is when the Busines Object returns a 'List' then ProductsListSerializer should be used for the whole List. and When Business Object returns 'List the CustomClientsSerializer should be used for the whole List. In my use-case I append additional elements to the serialized json 'eg:__count, __metadata , __references ' There is only one __count per Collection. Contentusing Can only be used on properties. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Seems the problem can be solved by registering serializer for a given JavaType (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind). But the simpleModule.addSerializer() accepts two parameters Class and Serilaizer. I am not able to find a method which can accept JavaType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It possible by extending the simplemodule or by extending com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module. I have taken the second approach. Below are the summary of changes

added method to take JavaType as parameter.

```
    public <T> TypedModule addSerializer(JavaType type, JsonSerializer<T> ser)
{
    if (_serializers == null) {
        _serializers = new TypedSerializers();
    }
    _serializers.addSerializer(type, ser);
    return this;
}
```

Above method adds the new serilaizer to

```
protected TypedSerializers _serializers = null;
```

The class 'TypedSerializers extends Serializers.Base'  stores all the typed serializers in a HashMap.

Changed the logic of findSerializer method in TypedSerializers

```
public JsonSerializer<?> findSerializer(SerializationConfig config,
        JavaType type, BeanDescription beanDesc) {

    Class<?> cls = type.getRawClass();
    ClassKey key = new ClassKey(cls);
    JsonSerializer<?> ser = null;
    if (_javaTypeMappings != null) {
        ser = _javaTypeMappings.get(type.toString());
        if (ser != null) {
            return ser;
        }
    }
 ..... process normal serilaizers ...
```

Below change is needed when registering a customserializer

```
    TypedModule simpleModule = new TypedModule("TypedModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));       
    JavaType productlist = this.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Product.class);
    JavaType clientlist = this.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Client.class);
    simpleModule.addSerializer(productlist,  new prodctlistserializer());
    simpleModule.addSerializer(clientlist, new clientlistserializer() );
    this.registerModule(simpleModule);
```

The resulting behaviour is, when 'List of type Product' is passed to ObjectMapper , it tries to locate a suitable serilaizer. We are maintaining the generic serializers in the map of _javaTypeMappings. The Objecmapper executes findSerializer. The findSerializer first checks for an avaliable serializer in _javaTypeMappings. In this case it returns prodctlistserializer. When 'List of type Client ' is passed it returns clientlistserializer.

I have taken all source code  under com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module to a package in my project and added above changes.

Answer (score 3):

Do you actually want serialization/deserialization of this type to be handled differently when it is inside of a collection? If not, you can just annotate `Product` class with something like: [`@JsonSerialize(using = ProductSerializer.class)`](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html#using%28%29) and Jackson will use your serializer anytime it encounters a `Product` (including inside of collections).

If you actually need different handling when inside of a collection you can annotate the class with something like: [`@JsonSerialize(using = ProductSerializer.class, contentUsing = ProductInCollectionSerializer.class)`](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html#contentUsing%28%29). This will do the same thing as above, except that `ProductInCollectionSerializer` will be used for serialization instead when Jackson encounters a collection containing `Product`.

*EDIT based on comment:*

Jackson will serialize a collection as a JSON array so there there is no place to put these additional properties. It sounds you like you want Jackson to return a JSON object containing a JSON array as well as some additional metadata. In this case, the best approach is wrap the `List<Product>` in an object such as:

```
public class ProductListWrapper {
    private final List<Product> products;

    public ProductListWrapper(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    @JsonProperty("_count")
    public int getCount() {
        return getProducts() == null ? 0 : getProducts().size();
    }
}
```

Jackson can then serialize this object without the need to write any custom serializers and will produce JSON looking like:

```
{
    "products": [....]
    "_count": 25
}
```

Comment: I have a business object which returns 'List<Product>' and another which returns List<Client>. The way I need is when the Busines Object returns a 'List<Product>' then  ProductsListSerializer should be used for the whole List. and When Business Object returns 'List<Client> the  CustomClientsSerializer  should be used for the whole List. In my use-case I append additional elements to the serialized json 'eg:__count, __metadata , __references '  There is only one __count per Collection. Contentusing Can only be used on properties. Any suggestions ?

Comment: based on your edit .. I have been exploring custom serializer  to avoid the wrapper object. With wrapper objects the domain model requires a change. I there a way to avoid polluting the domain model ?

Comment: Off the top of my head I can't think of an easy way to do what you want without doing something extreme like adding mix-in annotations to List.class. If you don't wrap the list, where will your serializer get the metadata? (besides things like '_count' which can be found on the list) I prefer to customize the JSON representation as little as possible and use annotations to customize whenever possible so that people can look at the object they're getting and know what JSON to expect. If you start writing serializers for different list types how can someone possibly know what JSON to expect?

Comment: I have modeled the customserializer as a spring component. The __count and __metadata are derived by injecting other business objects  into the customserializer. Effectively the __count is not the size of list. It is the count of records in the database. I am tweaking the JSON representation to meet requirements of ODATA. What JSON to expect is clearly defined in the ODATA spec. Hence I expect the developer to look at the RETST-web-service to understand the JSON rather than look at the object. Request your comments also on the answer I posted below. Thanks